# Adding a list to a doubly linked list

Tags: java

my question is how can I add a List to a DLL (doubly linked list)

```
@Override
public boolean addAll(List<? extends E> toAdd) throws NullPointerException
{
    DLLNode<E> dll = new DLLNode<E>(toAdd);
    for(int i = 1; i < toAdd.size(); i++)
    {
        head = (DLLNode) toAdd.get(1);
    }
}
```

DLLNode is the class for creating the doubly linked list.

```
public class DLLNode<E>
{   
     protected E element;
     protected List<? extends E> newElement;
     protected DLLNode prev;
     protected DLLNode next;

     public DLLNode(E toAdd)
     {
         this.element = toAdd;
     }

     public DLLNode(List<? extends E> toAdd)
     {
         this.newElement = toAdd;
     }
 }
```

This next bit is code from a JUnitTest. I will continue reading on the internet but I seriously cannot figure this out.

```
@Test
public <E> void testAddAllDLL()
{
    E temp, temp1;
    temp = (E) "Hello";
    temp1 = (E) "Hello again";
    DLL<E> list = new DLL<E>();
    DLL<E> addList = new DLL<E>();

    addList.add(temp);
    addList.add(temp1);
    list.addAll(addList);

    list.iterator();
}
```

list.addAll(addList); does not work and I've tried many different approaches. Thank you for reading...

Comment: Your iteration over `toAdd` starts at 1, it should start at 0, which is the index of the first element. Also, you should use the for-loop variable as parameter to the `get` method, not hard-code it to the value 1. That will fetch the same element for every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Check this http://java2novice.com/data-structures-in-java/linked-list/doubly-linked-list/ Although there seems to be an addNode method missing so I guess you iterate forward until you find the insertion point.. that code needs some work but it’s a start

Comment: The link I gave could also cause a memory leak because removeFirst/Last doesn’t actually nullify the unlinked node... so I’m guessing it stays in memory but inaccessible